# 1040 too many connection in php Pdo exception

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[This](http://svidzdownloader.com/Database.php) is my `Database.php`.  When I enter my website it shows me a `1040 too many connection` `Pdo` exception.

```
class Database extends \PDO
{

    public function __construct($dsn, $usr = null, $pwd = null, array $options = array())
    {
        $options = $options + $this->getDefaultOptions();
        @parent::__construct($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);
    }

    protected function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            \PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('Slim\\PDO\\Statement', array($this)),
            );
    }

   /**
    * @param array $columns
    *
    * @return SelectStatement
    */
    public function select(array $columns = array('*'))
    {
        return new SelectStatement($this, $columns);
    }

   /**
    * @param array $columnsOrPairs
    *
    * @return InsertStatement
    */
    public function insert(array $columnsOrPairs = array())
    {
        return new InsertStatement($this, $columnsOrPairs);
    }

   /**
    * @param array $pairs
    *
    * @return UpdateStatement
    */
    public function update(array $pairs = array())
    {
        return new UpdateStatement($this, $pairs);
    }

   /**
    * @param null $table
    *
    * @return DeleteStatement
    */
    public function delete($table = null)
    {
        return new DeleteStatement($this, $table);
    }
}
mysqli_close();
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed!  Please provide actual code in the question.  Can you also include the text of the exception message, and use Markdown formatting?  Thanks!

Comment: yes im sending the code

Comment: you can check the code

Answer (score -1):

If you get a Too many connections error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients.

The number of connections allowed is controlled by the max_connections system variable. Its default value is 100. If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/too-many-connections.html

Followings are possible solutions:

1) Increase the max connection setting by setting the global variable in mysql.

set global max_connection=2000;

Note: It will increase the server load.

2) Empty your connection pool as below :

FLUSH HOSTS;

3) check your processList and kill specific processlist if you don't want any of them.

http://www.easysolutionweb.com/mysql-tutorials/how-to-deal-with-too-many-connections-error-in-mysql?stack

Comment: Does your 'connect' code look  similar to this example?    https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_close.asp
 
Usually too free resources, you will need a close to make connection available to another user.

Comment: You may need to use brief (less than a MINUTE) General_Log to find out what is going on.